# executing multipal command in awk function

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

We are fetching a storage report in which we run a `isi-storagepool --list -v` including an awk function which does some calculation and prints the data at the end.

Current working command

```
isi storagepool list -v |awk 'function num2gb(n) { if (n ~ /T$/) return n / 1; return n / 1024; }
        /Requested Protection:/ { parity=substr($NF,length($NF)-1,1) }
        /Nodes:/ { nodes=$NF }
        /HDD Total/ { hdd_total=$NF }
        /HDD Used/ { hdd_used=num2gb($NF) }
        END {
                multiplier=nodes-parity
                total=hdd_total/nodes*multiplier
                used=hdd_used/nodes
                eu=used*multiplier*0.8
                et=total*0.8
                used1=eu/et*100
                print "parity =" parity
                print "NodeNumber =" nodes
                print "Total = " total " TB"
                print "Effective Total volume = " total*0.8 " TB"
                print "USED =" used1 " %"
                print "Effective used=" used*multiplier*0.8 " TB"
                print "Available volume=" (hdd_total-hdd_used)/nodes*multiplier*0.8 " TB" }'
```

Sample Output of the current working command

```
parity =1
NodeNumber =3
Total = 37.3013 TB
Effective Total volume = 29.8411 TB
USED =333975%
Effective used=534360 TB
Available volume=-534330 TB
```

Now we want to add some more information to the above sample output which we will  get from the below command.

```
# isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1
                                                  358G     n/a (R)    0.63% (T)
```

So that the requirement output should be as below

```
parity =1
NodeNumber =3
Total = 37.3013 TB
Effective Total volume = 29.8411 TB
USED =333975%
Effective used=534360 TB
Available volume=-534330 TB
Snapshot USED = 358G         # added output from the new command  # isi_classic snapshot usage
Snapshot USED % = 0.63%      # added output from the new command  # isi_classic snapshot usage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way to combine the output of several commands is to use a *group command*, like this:

```
{ date; date; } | awk 1
```

A possibly more elegant solution would be to use *process substitution*, like this:

```
awk 1 <(date) <(date)
```

The latter would allow use to use the old `NR==FNR` trick, for example.